# Android onItemClickListener for ArrayAdapter Gallery

Tags: android

I have read other similar posts but I didn't understand as I am a beginner. I am sorry if it's a duplicate.

I want to implement an ArrayAdapter to show in a GridView my array elements. And I want an onItemClickListener to open the clicked image in another Fragment, where I need it's position.

So, I have a Fragment in which I try implementing a custom gallery with GridView. I am trying to use an ArrayAdapter, where Item is a custom class for the gallery images. This is the code for my Fragment:

```
public class CaptureImagesGallery extends Fragment {
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter customGridAdapter;
Context context;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.images_gallery, container, false);
    context = container.getContext();
    Bitmap androidIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Nr. inmatriculare fata"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Nr. inmatriculare spate"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Serie sasiu"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Serie sasiu"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Poza diagonala 1"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Poza diagonala 2"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Poza diagonala 3"));
    gridArray.add(new Item(androidIcon, "Poza diagonala 4"));

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    customGridAdapter = new CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter(context, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    return view;
 }
}
```

And this is my ArrayList adapter

```
public class CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();


public CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                                            ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

    Item item = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;

    }

        static class RecordHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageItem;

            }
 }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: set onclick listener for your gridview. Are you want to implement onclick lister or ?

Comment: yes, I want to do an action when a Grid View item is clicked.

Comment: `gridView.setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
gridView .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

            CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter adapter = (CaptureImagesGalleryAdapter) parent.getAdapter(); 
            adapter.getItem(position);              // get your item position here

        // do whatever you want here 


        }

    });
```

Comment: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`